# .net framework 3.5 source code

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I'm trying to get hands on the **source code for .net Framework 3.5 SP1** for several hours now, and the place I [remember](http://web.archive.org/web/20131208040728/http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) getting 3.5 sources in the past, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx, is dead.

Just "3.5" without the "SP1" would be fine as well. It does not need to be bit-exact, but allow me to dig around and see how the stuff is implemented. But the parts of the 4.5 sources on referencesource I checked have changed too much to be useful for me.

I tried NetMassDownloader with the following arguments, but both say "not available" to all dlls, including the most basic ones like 'System.dll' and 'mscorlib.dll'

```
NetMassDownloader -d "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5"
Netmassdownloader -d c:\windows\Microsoft.NET -d "c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies"
```

So is it, in 2015, still somehow **possible to get (as much as possible of) the framework source v3.5 (SP1) code as a zip / tarball**?

---

N.B. Previously I tried to configure Visual Studio 2012 so that I can step into the .net sources in a myriad of suggested ways on the net, including pointing to the

```
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

to no avail. The simplest now seems to be to get a simple archive with the source files - if I could get my hands on them.

Comment: Is .NET Framework open source ? I doubt.

Comment: @Raptor Hmmmm..... In addition to the recent (a couple of weeks or months ago) open-sourcing of the framework (see e.g. https://github.com/dotnet), the source code for at least 3.5, 4.0, ... has been "available" for many, many years, if only "for reference" - which is all I'm asking for.

Comment: Did you go through these steps? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: The way back machine can still get you download URLs but they are not responsive.  It is just gone, it won't come back.  A decent decompiler like Reflector still works of course.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Hans Passant's comment:

> It is just gone, it won't come back. A decent decompiler like Reflector still works of course.

True or not, the free (as in beer) tool [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) created a complete VS solution from `System.data.dll` for me, and it almost compiles even. In any case this is enough for me to dig through the code to see how it actually is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a link to the Wayback Machine Web archive, as it can be also useful to someone else, for .Net Framework 4.0 version.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140305192412/http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

And then click on the "Download" button.

Comment: That link does not work for me - when I click it, I end up at the homepage https://web.archive.org/

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky Fixed. I didn't copy the address correctly. But am I not sure what version comes in the zip file I downloaded.

Comment: There is supposedly a .Net version 4 source in an even older older version of the site https://web.archive.org/web/20140208045133/http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx , but when I click, it it a Postback link, not leading to anywhere. The 6th link counting from the end.